# How can i un do a destroy() function in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to destroy an object, in my case is  "Player2" witch is in the same scene as "Player1" and then after Player1 position.x is past "baraj".position.x reapear. Basically how can i make a temporarly destroy method.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class switchCameras2 : MonoBehaviour
{


    public GameObject baraj;
    public GameObject CameraOne;
    public GameObject CameraTwo;
    public GameObject Player1;
    public GameObject Player2;
    public void Start()
    {
        CameraOne.SetActive(true);
        CameraTwo.SetActive(false);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (GameObject.Find("Player1").transform.position.x > GameObject.Find("baraj").transform.position.x)
        {
            CameraTwo.SetActive(true);
            CameraOne.SetActive(false);
            

        }
        if (GameObject.Find("Player1").transform.position.x < GameObject.Find("baraj").transform.position.x)
        {
            Destroy(Player2);
        }
        if (GameObject.Find("Player1").transform.position.x > GameObject.Find("baraj").transform.position.x)
        {
            Destroy(Player1);    
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: In gneral: Do not use `Find` ... and **if** you use it do not use it multiple times like every frame in `Update` .. and even then 3 times in a row ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `Destroy` it then you should make a new one with `Instantiate` method. If you don't want to `Destroy` it, one alternative is to deactivate it with `SetActive` like this  `Player1.SetActive(false);` and then enable it like this  `Player1.SetActive(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new GameObject variable called "U". And then right before destroying or in the start do U = player2.gameObject;
Now let's say you destroyed it and want to spawn. To do that we do
player2 = U.gameObject;
Instantiate(player2);

That will spawn player 2.

But as mentioned in the other answer .SetActive(false); would make things easier. Anyway if you still want to use destroy then that is how to do that. Good luck